# How to find the length of a multilevel list?

Tags: list, lisp, common-lisp

```
( setq list1 '( a ( b ( c d ) e ) f ( g h ) i ) )
( print ( length ( list1 ) ) )
```

The output here is 5 but I want the output to be 9. How to break the list and find the whole length?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to compute the length of `(flatten list)`, where `flatten` is a function that can be easily be implemented (or found on Stackoverflow). As said in another answer, you can also directly write a function that computes the sum. Yet another approach is to use the [SERIES](http://series.sourceforge.net/) package:

```
(defpackage :so (:use :cl :series))
(in-package :so)

(defun whole-length (tree)
  (collect-length (scan-lists-of-lists-fringe tree)))
```

#### Test

```
SO> (whole-length '( a ( b ( c d ) e ) f ( g h ) i ))
9
```

#### Macroexpanded code

The Series package can produce efficient iterative loops from a high-level functional code. Here `scan-lists-of-lists-fringe` generates a stream of leaves in a tree, using its own stack. The `collect-length` function counts the elements being generated.
Here below is the macroexpansion of `(collect-length ...)`.

```
(LET* ((#:OUT-1035 TREE))
  (LET (#:LEAVES-1032 (#:STATE-1034 (LIST (LIST #:OUT-1035))) (#:NUMBER-1029 0))
    (DECLARE (TYPE LIST #:STATE-1034)
             (TYPE FIXNUM #:NUMBER-1029))
    (TAGBODY
     #:LL-1036
      (IF (NULL #:STATE-1034)
          (GO SERIES::END))
      (SETQ #:LEAVES-1032 (CAR #:STATE-1034))
      (SETQ #:STATE-1034 (CDR #:STATE-1034))
      (SETQ #:LEAVES-1032 (CAR #:LEAVES-1032))
      (WHEN (NOT (ATOM #:LEAVES-1032))
        (DO ((SERIES::NS #:LEAVES-1032 (CDR SERIES::NS))
             (SERIES::R NIL (CONS SERIES::NS SERIES::R)))
            ((NOT (CONSP SERIES::NS))
             (SETQ #:STATE-1034 (NRECONC SERIES::R #:STATE-1034))))
        (GO #:LL-1036))
      (INCF #:NUMBER-1029)
      (GO #:LL-1036)
     SERIES::END)
    #:NUMBER-1029))
```

Answer (score 3):

It seems that you don't want to count the length, but the number of atoms (the leaves in the tree) of a given list.
To do it, you want to define a function that will check if the argument is an atom or a list. In the first case it will return 1 (the number of atoms in an atom). In the second case, it will return the sum of the atoms of each individual branch in the list, calculated using the same function.
That should be enough to get you started.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is a way to count the leafs in a tree represented as nested lists. Here is a quick, easy, functional way to do it:

```
(defun count-leafs (tree)
  "Counts the number of leafs in a tree represented as nested lists"
  (cond ((null tree) 0)
        ((atom tree) 1)
        (t (+ (count-leafs (car tree))
              (count-leafs (cdr tree))))))
```

This function will traverse all the nodes of the tree and sum all "non-list" nodes. If a certain node is not a list, then it must be an atom (a leaf).

```
(count-leafs '(1 2 3)) ; => 3
(count-leafs '(1 (22) 3)) ; => 3
(count-leafs '(1 (2 3 4 5 2) 3)) ; => 7
(count-leafs '(1 (2 3 ((4)) 5 2) 3)) ; => 7
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me, thanks everyone. :)

```
( setq list1 '( a ( b ( c d ) e ) f ( g h ) i ) )
( print ( length list1 ) )
( defun flatten ( list1 )
  ( if ( atom list1 )
      ( list list1 )
      ( loop for a in list1
            appending ( flatten a )
             )
       )
    )
( print ( length ( flatten list1 ) ) )
```

Comment: Note that your code does not follow the Lisp coding style. In particular, you don't put parentheses on their own lines and don't let them with so much space around them. http://people.ace.ed.ac.uk/staff/medward2/class/moz/cm/doc/contrib/lispstyle.html

Comment: I find this much less readable than the style coredump suggests.

Comment: @BartvanNierop That suggest you don't usually read lisp code.

Comment: 'Ok thanks, this is just for easy on viewing. '  How so?

Comment: @Sylwester Quite the opposite.